# Dynamically constructed update statement from associative array

Tags: php, string, associative-array, implode

I'm trying to create a dynamically constructed UPDATE statement based on an associative array that looks as follows:

```
$lastid = $app['database']->dynamicUpdate('table', [
    'name' => $name,
    'ticket' => $ticket,
], $id);
```

The dynamicUpdate function:

```
public function dynamicUpdate($table, $parameters, $id)
{
    $query = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET (%s) WHERE id = %s', $table, implode(', ', array_keys($parameters).'= :'.array_keys($parameters)), $id);
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($parameters);
    return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

However it returns the below error when I simply echo out the $query variable(removed all other code inside dynamicUpdate):

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
>   EditProduct.php on line 21 UPDATE table
>   SET () WHERE id = 10

Comment: Implode requires an array as the 2nd argument, you pass string. Array keys returns array you force array to string conversion.

Comment: Your second argument to implode is supposed to be an array.  You have `array_keys($parameters).'= :'.array_keys($parameters)`.  You can't concatenate an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can only implode a single array and not manipulate the content like you are trying to at the same time.  A foreach can easily build up the part you need instead...

```
$set = "";
foreach ( $parameters as $name=>$param) {
    $set .= $name."= :".$name.",";
}
$set=rtrim($set,",");
$parameters["keyID"] = $id;
$query = "UPDATE $table SET $set WHERE id = :keyID";
```

It's also worth putting the ID into the array for bind parameters just in case and including some dummy name for it.

Comment: Wouldn't this also cause `keyID= :keyID` right before the WHERE clause?

Comment: I add it in after I build the list of values to set.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to implode must be an array

what about this solution to implement the query

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET ', $table);
foreach($parameters as $key=>$value)
    $query .= "$key=:$key, ";
$query = rtrim($query,", ");
$query .= sprintf('WHERE id = %s', $id);
```